# How to make a 3D point around the other 3D point

Tags: wpf, math, 3d

eg:

```
   Vector3D point = new Vector3D(1, 0, 0);
   var targetRotatePoint = new Point3D(-1, 0, 0);
   AxisAngleRotation3D axisAngle = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), 180);
   RotateTransform3D myRotateTransform = new RotateTransform3D(axisAngle,targerRotatePoint);

   var result= myRotateTransform.Transform(point);\\is same point*myRotateTransform.Value
```

the reult is [-1,0,0] but I hope the result is [-3,0,0] .

i also thinking another Method first Rotate and then Translation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line has to be:

```
Point3D point = new Point3D(1, 0, 0);
```

In your code you are transforming a vector and the result of rotating a vector is independent of the center of the rotation.